# How to download image assets with CURL in SurveryMonkey with response/bulk API request?

Tags: php, api, curl, surveymonkey

I need to download all the images from the surveryMonkey assets. For that I have called API `https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys/$surveryId/responses/bulk`. I got the JSON response like this,

```
{
"per_page": 100,
"total": 24,
"data": [
    {
        "total_time": 186,
        "href": "https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys/123/responses/10523886584",
        "custom_variables": {
            "UserName": "abc",
            "LocationID": "560323dfd65"
        },
        "ip_address": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
        "id": "123",
        "logic_path": {},
        "date_modified": "2019-02-12T00:33:27+00:00",
        "response_status": "completed",
        "custom_value": "",
        "analyze_url": "https://www.surveymonkey.com/analyze/",
        "pages": [
            {
                "id": "54495728",
                "questions": [
                    {
                        "id": "198653099",
                        "answers": [
                            {
                                "text": "82D5975A-B014-4EB7-AD62-B2174B973BA5.png",
                                "download_url": "https://www.surveymonkey.com/analyze/files/download/?survey_id=123&files=U8_2Fi7f1PB269nd_2FM6CyP3kWa_2F9ca5HVlxAxzmWVv_2Bq11rTOBMsWPwxppe3CRarNKvcVYgOwAuQ_2BDm3HHIB_2FIal6T4qnXg_2FbHY15ldm_2BPKVyBbxpETS2W6bvLUDdfRAnUfEiaKwQrZf_2FBU0_2Fo5wfqCKu5tPqP6399MmosgrQfGpc_3D",
                                "content_type": "image/png"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "198653103",
                        "answers": [
                            {
                                "text": "576ED35A-7E1E-4CA8-BCF0-0A12224D8126.jpeg",
                                "download_url": "https://www.surveymonkey.com/analyze/files/download/?survey_id=123&files=U8_2Fi7f1PB269nd_2FM6CyP3kWa_2F9ca5HVlxAxzmWVv_2Bq11rTOBMsWPwxppe3CRarNKSRAwmNg4FdLTI8zKRY7_2BviD_2B4oTmqgxfJVWE3sLbJwXTlr_2FDl_2FnmZvLG6p6jhGCcaQU7S7iHX_2BjqyMNIrbJpfrzx84FQTOK_2BFmNybyRAc48_3D",
                                "content_type": "image/jpeg"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "198653104",
                        "answers": [
                            {
                                "text": "EE8C57E7-6EE2-4211-817E-5E2A5C4EAAB6.jpeg",
                                "download_url": "https://www.surveymonkey.com/analyze/files/download/?survey_id=123&files=U8_2Fi7f1PB269nd_2FM6CyP3kWa_2F9ca5HVlxAxzmWVv_2Bq11rTOBMsWPwxppe3CRarNKt_2FzuXUNhpQ_2F4JXuH6Vvnp3_2B_2Bgkf9Wn9I_2BQ_2BQyqp9Va999YY3VwfsKNeNZV94CzT8nje_2BCzSZMGAdmd6faqMIEI_2BlJj1AUNbuLmTczecBdPc_3D",
                                "content_type": "image/jpeg"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "page_path": [],
        "recipient_id": "",
        "collector_id": "123",
        "date_created": "2019-02-12T00:30:20+00:00",
        "survey_id": "123",
        "collection_mode": "default",
        "edit_url": "https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/?sm=cg",
        "metadata": {}
    },        
],
"page": 1,
"links": {
    "self": "https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys/123/responses/bulk?page=1&per_page=100"
}
```

}

I need CURL request which get all the image from `download_url` the surveryMonkey and place to the local server directory.

Here is the CURL request code: This redirect with error 403 status.

```
$username = 'xxx@example.com';
$password = 'xxx';
$cookie_file_path = "/tmp/cookies.txt";
$loginUrl = "https://www.surveymonkey.com/user/sign-in/"; 

//init curl
$ch = curl_init();

//Set the URL to work with
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);

// ENABLE HTTP POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Set the post parameters
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'username='.$username.'&password='.$password);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//execute the request (the login)
$store = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($store);
```

Comment: I know you cab get Idea from here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/FileAbstractionLayerReference/8.7/UsingFal/Examples/FileFolder/Index.html
You have to register image using fal

Comment: Your comment really makes sense If you're using extBase! But, in this picture, I'm using third party API (SuveryMonkey) to retrieve Image and I'm unable to access Image without login to the third party API portal.

Comment: You can generate Outh token using Outh2.0 so with every request you not need to logged in